# Scala main constructor initialisation

Tags: scala

Why does the following class throw an exception at initialisation:

```scala
class Test {
  val att = throw new Exception("")
}
new Test() // raises Exception
```

Whereas the following class doesn't?

```scala
class Test {
  val att = Seq((1, "a")).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(throw new Exception(""))
}
new Test() // doesn't raise Exception
(new Test()).att // raises Exception
```

Comment: Everything inside the class body is constructor.

Comment: I can't reproduce, both throw the exception when the instance is created.

Comment: Then it must be a problem with IntelliJ, although I'm having this problem even when running the example remotely in Jenkins. This is really weird.

Comment: @Prassi what is your **Scala** version? Are you sure this is the same code that reproduces the problem? How are you running the code in **Jenkins**?

Answer (score 1):

`vals` defined in a `class` are evaluated on instantiation of the class.

Since the `val` defined by this class has a `throws` keyword, it will throw an exception upon instantiation. Actually, all the examples will throw an exception.

To avoid this problem, define the val `att` as a new `Exception` but don't `throw` it upon creation.

```scala
class Test {
  val att: Exception = new Exception("test")
}


new Test()             // doesn't raise Exception
(new Test()).att       // doesn't Exception

throw (new Test().att) // throws exception
```